# How to validate wsdl in spring-boot framework

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, web-services, wsdl

Is there any way to validate wsdl in spring-boot webservice? I know how to validate Xsd file using **PayloadValidatingInterceptor**

```
@Override
  public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
    PayloadValidatingInterceptor validatingInterceptor = new PayloadValidatingInterceptor();
    validatingInterceptor.setValidateRequest(true);
    validatingInterceptor.setValidateResponse(true);
    validatingInterceptor.setXsdSchema(schema());
    interceptors.add(validatingInterceptor);
  }
 @Bean
  public XsdSchema schema() {
    return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("example.xsd"));
  }
```

But the problem is that I do not have separate xsd because of that i can not set schema using "PayloadValidatingInterceptor". All i have is wsdl n it is itself containing all element n all.

could you please suggest me any way to achieve above requirement?